# how to get more signficant digits to print from a long value?

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to print a long value held by `elapsed`, can someone help me with the format of how to do it?

This prints `0.0`

but i know it has more significant digits (maybe like .0005324 or something)

```
System.out.println("It took " + (double)elapsed + " milliseconds to complete SELECTION_SORT algorithm.");
```

'

```
    System.currentTimeMillis();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int sortedArr[] = selectionSort(arr1);
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;


    System.out.println("\n///////////SELECTIONSort//////////////");
    System.out.println("\nSelection sort implemented below prints a sorted list:");
    print(sortedArr);
    System.out.printf("It took %.7f ms....", elapsed);

    //System.out.println("It took " + (double)elapsed + " milliseconds to complete SELECTION_SORT algorithm.");'
```

'

```
    private static int[] selectionSort(int[] arr) {

    int minIndex, tmp;
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        minIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (arr[j] < arr[minIndex])
                minIndex = j;
        if (minIndex != i) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
            arr[minIndex] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return arr;

}'
```

Comment: If it has that many significant digits, it'll print them. If you're expecting a nonzero value, the issue is probably earlier in the code (I can think of at least one possibility)

Comment: whats the type of `elapsed`? Is it really `long` as stated in the question?

Comment: Try typing `elapsed = 5324;` right before the println.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the format won't give you more resolution which is what your real problem is hee if you print 1 ms with 7 digits you just get 1.0000000 every time.  This doesn't help you at all.

What you need is a high resolution timer

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
int sortedArr[] = selectionSort(arr1);
long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

System.out.println("\n///////////SELECTIONSort//////////////");
System.out.println("\nSelection sort implemented below prints a sorted list:");
print(sortedArr);
System.out.printf("It took %.3f ms....", elapsed / 1e6);
```

However, if you do this once you are fooling yourself because Java compiles code dynamically and gets fast the more you run it.  It can get 100x faster or more making the first number you see pretty useless.

Normally I suggest you run loops many times and *ignore the first 10,000+ times*.  This will change the results so much that you will see that the first digit was completely wrong.  I suggest you try this

```
for(int iter = 1; iter<=100000; iter *= 10) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int[] sortedArr = null
    for(int i=0;i<iter;i++) 
        sortedArr = selectionSort(arr1);
    long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

    System.out.println("\n///////////SELECTIONSort//////////////");
    System.out.println("\nSelection sort implemented below prints a sorted list:");
    print(sortedArr);
    System.out.printf("It took %.3f ms on average....", elapsed / 1e6 / iter);
}
```

You will see you results improve 10x maybe even 100x just by running the code for longer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [print formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).  For a `double` or `float`, to get 7 places after the decimal place, you would do:

```
System.out.printf("It took %.7f ms....", elapsed);
```

**EDIT**:
You are actually using a `long`, not a `double`, so you cannot have significant digits, because `long` only takes on integer values.

Comment: i got an error,Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Long

Comment: ok got it, but what should i do if i want to actually see more digits? i can understan that it close to 0, but not zero exactly

Comment: @ClearMist You can use `System.nanoTime()`, that will get you more digits.  Remember, these values are integers (`long`, but nonetheless integers), so you will never get any digits to the right of the decimal place, but `nanoTime()` will be a larger number, if nanoseconds suffice.

Comment: Adding 7 zeros to the end of the answer isn't very helpful.  While this is the answer to the OP's question, the problem is actually you want more resolution and you want to warmup up the code. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 String.format("%.7f",longvalue);
by using above line you can format your long or any floating point numbers. Here 7 is referred how many digits you want after '.' .

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '.'
 at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
 at SelectionSort.main(SelectionSort.java:23)

Comment: i tried this,   System.out.printf(String.format("%.7",elapsed));

Comment: Just use print method

Comment: Sorry. I have forget to enter f. Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

A `long` is an integer value and does not have decimal places.

To get an approximation of the runtime, run the same sort in a loop, say 1000 times and then divide the measured time by 1000.

For example:

```
System.out.println("It took " + ((double)elapsed) / NUMBER_OF_ITERATONS);
```